# XPath to Parse "href" from /a tag?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

I have HTML code like this:

```html
<a href="/images/big_1.jpg" class="class-a">
   <img class="class-img" src="/images/small_1.jpg"/>
      <span class="class-span">
         <img src="/images/img_1.png">
      </span>
</a>

<a href="/images/big_2.jpg" class="class-a">
   <img class="class-img" src="/images/small_2.jpg"/>
      <span class="class-span">
         <img src="/images/img_2.png">
      </span>
</a>
```

I successfully grabbed the all url's from first /a tag with this:

```html
//a[@class="class-a"]/@href
```

for example it would return this url's:

```
/images/big_1.jpg,/images/small_1.jpg,/images/img_1.png
```

But I only need this url's:

```
/images/big_1.jpg,/images/big_2.jpg
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//a[@class="class-a"]/@href` would only return the `href` attribute values of the `a` elements with "class-a" `class` attribute. In your case these are:

```
/images/big_1.jpg,/images/big_2.jpg
```

In other words, your current approach is the correct one.

---

If you mean to get the `src` and `href` attribute of the `a` elements as well as all the children elements. If this is the case, you can use [`descendant-or-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant-or-self) and `@*` with `name()` to check the attribute names:

```
//a[@class = 'class-a']/descendant-or-self::*/@*[name() = 'src' or name() = 'href']
```

Comment: No, i need only href.

Comment: @Reforket well, then your expression should work. Don't see the problem, could you please elaborate on how your input is different from the desired one? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something with my parser. Because the code that you wrote does not work. //a[@class="class-a"]/@href I understand it is not operating properly, even though it should give what I need.